# How to make a maximum intensity projection of 3D data?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to make a maximum intensity projection of my 2D data, which has several intensity values in the third dimension and therefore makes the data 3D. So I want to take the maximum intensity of each pixel. Is there an easy way to do this in Mathematica? Like, how to take the maximum value in the third dimension?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Can you give a sample of how your data looks like?

Comment: There's probably a better way than this: `Map[Max, data, {2}]`...

Answer (score 4):

I suppose `Map[Max, data, {2}]` is simplest.  And if the entries are `Real` and exceed the `SystemOptions[]` `"CompileOptions"` setting of `"MapCompileLength"`, which is

```
Fold[#2 /. #1 &, SystemOptions[], {"CompileOptions", "MapCompileLength"}]
(*  100  *)
```

then it will be auto-compiled and be efficient.

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomReal[1, {2, 3, 4}];
Grid[data,  Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> Scaled[1/3]]
Grid[Map[Max, data, {2}],  Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> Scaled[1/3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]